# Is there a way to change the default drill through behavior?

Tags: c#, sql, ssas, cube

It has been said there is no way to change the default drill through behavior with ssas .  However, if we look closely we discover that we can actually exercise a bit more flexibility.
currently double click opens a new sheets an populates data in it, but it is using some default fields rather than fields assigned in the Action .
Is there a way to change the default drill through behavior using a code C# in which we define columns we want to show by default ? 
Regards .

Comment: Reporting services already allows you to specify whether to show/hide columns based on logic stipulated in custom expressions, is this the sort of thing you mean? Regards

Comment: @SelectDistinct I mean create a table to support drill through something like that http://beyondrelational.com/modules/24/syndicated/477/Posts/19139/configuring-drill-to-details-behavior-in-powerpivot-part-1.aspx  and I am looking for a way to dynamically change the columns which I would  like to preview .

Comment: I assume that you are talking about SSAS Tabular?  You can most definitely change the fields in SSAS multi-dimensional. For Tabular, you can use BIDS Helper to define drillthrough actions by measure group http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Tabular%20Actions%20Editor&referringTitle=Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a long time, but just so other people can know, if you go to the bottom of where you define the drillthrough action and expand additional properties, you can set the default property to true.  The action you defined will then become the default drillthrough action.