# DRILLTHROUGH not returning Dimension Keys

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, ssas-tabular, drillthrough

I have a created a very simple SSAS tabular model following Kimbal's Fact/Dimension philosophy (e.g. one fact table and 2 dimension tables (date. employee). When I use the DRILLTHROUGH statement (MDX) it returns the measure granular data (as expected), however there is no dimension key data (i.e. DateID, EmployeeID etc.) that are dimensions of the underlying fact table.

Given the [DRILLTHROUGH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/mdx-data-manipulation-drillthrough?view=sql-server-2017) statement says:

> "Unless otherwise specified, the columns returned include all granularity attributes for all dimensions related to the measure group of the specified measure, other than many-to-many dimensions"

I was expecting the Dimension keys to be displayed.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If using SSAS 2012 then the results can be modified through an VS2015 [helper](https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/features/TabularActionsEditor/) (note:Warning: While actions work in Tabular models, they are not officially supported by Microsoft. If you encounter a bug in how Tabular handles actions and open a support case, Microsoft may not provide support.)

If using SSAS 2017 then the results can be modified though a new [feature](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/controlling-drillthrough-using-detail-rows-expressions-in-dax/).

Other articles on this topic:
[Is there a way to change the default drill through behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353476/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-default-drill-through-behavior)